# How to stop/start a remote tomcat based on IP address

Tags: tomcat

Now I'm using the below script to start & stop the tomcat in a server.

Now i want to modify it to stop or start a remote tomcat base on IP address.

Please give me some suggestions.

```
CATALINA_HOME=/home/tomcat; export CATALINA_HOME
start() {
        echo -n "Starting Tomcat:  "
        su $TOMCAT_OWNER -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh           
        status=$(tail -50  $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out | grep "Server startup")
        echo "$status"
}
stop() {
        echo -n "Stopping Tomcat: "
        su $TOMCAT_OWNER -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh              
        ps -eaf | grep "$CATALINA_HOME/bin" | grep -v "grep" |awk -F " " '{print $2}' >> proc_id
        cat proc_id | while read line
        do
        kill -9 $line >> Tomcat_stop.log
        done
        rm -rf proc_id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't just ssh onto the server and restart tomcat?

That would be the normal way of restarting the tomcat remotely.

Comment: I've the access to ssh and i can create my scripts there to run, but whenever i need to restart/stop/start I've to go each server and tomcat to stop/start. So, my need is a centralized stop/start script to access many tomcats (say, more than 15 tomcats !) which resides in several servers; so, based on my need I can give the IP address of the server and particular tomcat name to stop/start. That will save my time and makes the complexity less in handling the tomcats.

Comment: It might be just as easy then to write a shell script that loops through a list of IP addresses and restarts tomcat for each IP.  So each time you get a new server, you just add to a text file the IP address.

Comment: Can you pls give some examples ? So that i could take that Idea to try and implement that with my script.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really the best shell scripter (and I've not got access to linux / putty right now, so it would just be a best guess).  You'd probably have more luck if you made a new question asking how to write the script if you had a go at it and said where you're stuck.  I definitely think writing a bash script is the way to go rather than any other method.  The code you have above already does most of the work, you just need to add the ssh loop on.